# Code won't advance past wait function for conditional variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

So, I've been trying to get a better understand of how condition variables work and I've written the following code that tries to implement reading and writing from the same text file:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <thread>

    using namespace std;

    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable conditionVariable;
    ifstream readFile;
    ofstream writeFile;
    bool doneReading=false;
    bool doneWriting=false;

    void readFromFile()
    {
        string line;

        readFile.open("./testFile.txt");

        if(readFile.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Successfully opened file!" << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Failed to open file..." << "\n";
        }

        cout << "The file contents are:" << "\n";
        while(getline(readFile,line))
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);

            conditionVariable.wait(lock, [] () {return doneWriting;});

            cout << line << "\n";

            doneReading=true;

            lock.unlock();

            conditionVariable.notify_one();
        }
        readFile.close();
    }

    void writeToFile()
    {
        string input;

        writeFile.open("./testFile.txt");

        cout << "Enter something you want to write to the text file:" << "\n";
        cin >> input;
        cout << "Going to write " << input << " to the file" << "\n";

        if(writeFile.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Successfully opened file!" << "\n";

            unique_lock<mutex> lock2(mtx);

            /////////PROGRAM WON'T ADVANCE PAST THIS LINE/////////////
            conditionVariable.wait(lock2, [] () {return doneReading;}); 

            cout << "After calling the wait function for the condition variable" << "\n";

            writeFile << input;

            doneWriting=true;

            lock2.unlock();

            conditionVariable.notify_one();

            writeFile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Failed to open file..." << "\n";
        }
    }


    int main()
    {

        int i;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            thread t1(readFromFile);
            thread t2(writeToFile);
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }
    }
```

And, I modeled my use of boolean variables after the following [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) from 
cppreference.com (scroll down to the bottom to see the example code). However, it has something do the predicate I am passing to the wait function, and I'm not quite sure what is wrong with it. If someone could give some insight, that would be brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: You have a [data race](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) with `doneReading` and `doneWriting` because they are accessed by multiple threads. Try using [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) instead.

Comment: @Phantom - There is a data race here, but not with those variables. As implemented, those variables create deadlock. The data races are with regard to cout (jumbled output) and the data file. If the file doesn't yet exist, there's a race between `readFromFile` and `writeToFile`. If `readFromFile` wins the race, it loses because the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial state is:

```
bool doneReading=false;
bool doneWriting=false;
```

The first thing `readFromFile` does to these variables is sit and wait for `doneWriting` to become `true`

```
conditionVariable.wait(lock, [] () {return doneWriting;});
```

The first thing `writeFromFile` does to these variables is sit and wait for `doneReading` to become `true`

```
conditionVariable.wait(lock2, [] () {return doneReading;});
```

Neither condition will become true.

Note that the cppreference example does something very different: one thread begins by executing `cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});` while the other begins by executing `ready=true;`